# How to view all users by admin in asp.net empty webform project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project in asp.net (using empty web form) and I have done coding for user authentication(login,signup,home page etc) in my project using membership.Now I want admin to view all the registered user and search them . Is there any tutorial or article for admin panel using empty web form project.

Thanks

Comment: You can simply load users from db and show on page and this page is accessible only to admin.

Comment: ok do you know any article or tutorial for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the below link, that would help you to learn the basic of Membership and Roles systems in asp.net.

[click here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx)